# Table with continuous dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am working on a time recording programm and since persons have different time models (fulltime work, parttime (e.g. only working on Monday 3 hours and Wednesday 5 hours). I have to calculate everything on daily base. The Table i have in my mind is:

**Fields:**

```
Workers_ID
Date
Weekday name
Hours to work
Hours worked
```

Since everybody can work (hours worked) every day in a year i need a continuous Date entry (e.g. from `01.01.2013`-now) OR from `01.01.2013`-`01.01.2100` or so.

But since i am very new with sql i have no idea how to accomplish that. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you please give an example with a few records that are going to be stored in this table?

Comment: of course. 1, 03-27-2013, Monday, 8, 7 1 Tuesday, 4, 7 and so forth. So i can make summaries for each week or for each month or year and can show the overtime and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you need, but here is a way to get continuous dates between two dates:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '2013-01-01'
SET @endDate = GETDATE()


;WITH CTE_Dates AS
(
    SELECT @startDate AS DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,DT) FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE DT <= @endDate
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: i never worked with CTE´s before and have one question. when i put your code into a new query i dont know how to work with the CTE_Dates table. E.g. if i write Select TOP 10 FROM CTE_Dates after the line OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) nothing happens and i get the message: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."

Comment: CTE works like a temporary view or something like a sub-query written in front. It's only valid for the next statementa and OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) comes at the end, so you can't use it anymore. If you need data from CTE in multiple statements consider using a #temp table to store dates from CTE

Comment: Some links about CTE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: ah ok! Great thank you very much. I will try to store the dates in a temp table then.